iOS 18 - How to clear tabbar order persisted by iPad
In iOS 18, Apple introduced the ability to elevate the tab bar on iPad, allowing for customization. The customized order is persisted by the system and retrieved upon reopening the app.
How can I clear this order or forcefully set the default tab order programmatically?
